# How to read specific bits of an unsigned int

Tags: c, bit, unsigned, uint8t

I have an uint8_t and I need to read/write to specific bits.  How would I go about doing this.  Specifically what I mean is that I need to write and then later read the first 7 bits for one value and the last bit for another value.

edit: forgot to specify, I will be setting these as big endian

Comment: What is _first_ and _last_ will depend on your architecture. Typically people talk about least and most significant bits for this reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for *bitmasking*. Learning how to use C's bitwise operators: `~`, `|`, `&`, `^` and so on will be of huge help, and I recommend you look them up.

Otherwise -- want to read off the least significant bit?

```
uint8_t i = 0x03;

uint8_t j = i & 1; // j is now 1, since i is odd (LSB set)
```

and set it?

```
uint8_t i = 0x02;
uint8_t j = 0x01;

i |= (j & 1); // get LSB only of j; i is now 0x03
```

Want to set the seven most significant bits of i to the seven most significant bits of j?

```
uint8_t j = 24; // or whatever value
uint8_t i = j & ~(1); // in other words, the inverse of 1, or all bits but 1 set
```

Want to read off these bits of i?

```
i & ~(1);
```

Want to read the Nth (indexing from zero, where 0 is the LSB) bit of i?

```
i & (1 << N);
```

and set it?

```
i |= (1 << N); // or-equals; no effect if bit is already set
```

These tricks will come in pretty handy as you learn C.

Comment: To set the LSB, you want: `i |= j & 1;`, not `i &= j & 1` (or `i = i & (j & 1)`)