# How to format I2C data from device data sheet?

Tags: c, i2c, bitmask

I recently started a project with a **Nordic NRF52832 DK**. To this board I have connected one **DRV2605** linear resonant actuator driver. Before I moved to the Nordic board, I was prototyping on an Arduino with a provided library for the DRV2605, so that was pretty simple.

Now, I am attempting to initialize and control the DRV2605 on my own by writing to the specified registers from the [device setup guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa189/sloa189.pdf).

[Section 1.6.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZNwS.png) is what I have been looking at. Let's say I want to write to the **feedback control register**. I know that the address is **0x1A** and that I need to write a value that corresponds to the four listed settings. What I am stuck on is how to actually create the data I need to write. The table has a column for what I assume is the range of bits I'll be modifying for each setting?

From looking at the chart (using the default settings) I'd assume the data I would need to write would be **13331122**. If I plug that value into a dec to hex converter I get **CB6AB2**. Does "B6" portion of that value correlate to the "Value (Hex)" column from the chart or is it coincidence?

Here's the code I would use to write to the FC reg:

```
#define DRV_ADDR 0x5A
uint8_t fc_reg[2] = {0x1A, 13331122};
nrf_drv_twi_tx(&m_twi, DRV_ADDR, fc_reg, sizeof(fc_reg), false);
```

From doing some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626652/how-to-read-specific-bits-of-an-unsigned-int) it seems bit masking might be what I'm missing? This still doesn't really explain the value mismatch from the chart.

I'd really appreciate any help I can get on this, thanks!

Comment: You can't send more that one byte (0-255) per I²C transaction. There is SMBus protocol, that supports **byte** packages (block transfers).

Comment: @0andriy I2C can have any number of data frames following the address frame(s).

Comment: @ThomasJager, yes, I formulated it wrong. The main point that it can't send more than one byte as data frame. If 16-bit value is expected, then it would be 2 data frames.

Comment: @0andriy Ah, perfect, I see what you meant

Comment: @SpinBower I don't think you've quite understood how bits work. The default bits appear to be `1_011_01_10` (separated by field), which is the `0xB6` you expect. 13331122 is much larger than a single byte.

Comment: @ThomasJager Wow, that made it so much clearer. I knew 13331122 was wrong but I wasn't entirely sure why. I just needed the binary equivalents!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the provided screenshot you can see that the Feedback Control register has an address 0x1A, more so, that register holds 1 byte of information. It effectively serves as a bitflag where each bit represents something different. For example only bit 7 represents LRA. So, if you were to write 0x80(DEC 128) into that register, it would turn on LRA and if you wanted to enable/configure something else, it would just be a bitwise OR of the 0x80. You have the right idea for the frames your constructing, however, it should instead look something like this for LRA.

> uint8_t fc_reg[2] = {0x1A, 0x80};

Obviously, replace the 0x80 with whatever flags you would like to set.